# Function parameters and type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, function

In the declaration of this function, if I remove `<IFirst extends {}, ISecond extends {}>`, the compiler reports an error; is not the return value the type after the double dot? What's the meaning of `<IFirst extends {}, ISecond extends {}>` after the name of the function? Why I have to put both `<IFirst extends {}, ISecond extends {}>` and `: IFirst & ISecond` on the declaration? I checked the documentation and surfed the Internet, but I cannot find the answer.

```js
function extend<IFirst extends {}, ISecond extends {}>(
    IFirst: IFirst,
    ISecond: ISecond
): IFirst & ISecond {}
```

Comment: _if I remove ,_. What do you remove?

Comment: @Evaldas Buinauskas: sorry; question updated; format problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) and it's one of the advanced types in TypeScript.

It's going to combine all properties from IFirst and ISecond into one.

`<IFirst extends {}, ISecond extends {}>` is a generic type and `extends` keyword means that `IFirst` or `ISecond` has to be compatible with `{}`.

So basically this function accepts two parameters that can be cast to `{}` and will ensure that return type will have properties from both first and second objects.

```js
function extend<TFirst extends {}, TSecond extends {}>(
    first: TFirst,
    second: TSecond
): TFirst & TSecond {
  return Object.assign({}, first, second);
}

const extended = extend({a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 });

console.log(extended);
```

`extended` will have a definition of:

```js
const extended: {
    a: number;
    b: number;
} & {
    c: number;
    d: number;
}
```

Comment: so <TFirst extends {}, TSecond extends {}> refers to the input parameters and not the output parameters, right?

Comment: In your case it dictates both, because it dictates the input and the output (intersection type). But normally you can think of them as dictating input parameters.

Comment: @Yellow75 You should read [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) for more information about generics ;) And [more specifically](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)